# Why is a SUBST'd drive inaccessible via shortcut or Run menu, but works fine from My Computer?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-server-2003, subst

I have shortcuts to C:, D:, and E: in my quick launch bar.  C and E work fine when I click on them, but D does nothing (that I can see) when I click on it.  D and E are both `SUBST`'d drives pointing to folders that happen to be network shares.  (I do this rather than mapping them so it doesn't have to go through the network layer--that way it works faster and I still get recycle bin functionality, etc.)

If I go Start->Run and type D: or D:\, I get an error box saying:

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Create an association in the Folder Options control panel.

If I go to My Computer and double-click the D drive, it comes up fine.  Also, if I type `\\servername\sharename` pointing to the same place, it comes up fine.

This just started happening this morning, out of the blue.  It has been working fine ever since I set it up.  Why might this be?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized to be useful to future visitors (a reboot fixed it).

Comment: Also, you aren't bypassing the network layer, and this offers no improvement in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic Windows solution: reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider mapping a drive instead of using *SUBST*. Mapping a drive will survive reboots cleanly, and I've not seen any of the behavior you're describing.

To map a drive, choose *Tools -> Map Network Drive* in Windows explorer. The drive you'll be mapping is:

```
\\[your-computer-name]\[drive-letter]$\[path]\[to]\[folder]
```

EG, if your computer was called *MYCOMP*, and you wanted to map to *C:\Program Files*, the path you'd enter at the first step of the Map Network Drive wizard would be:

```
\\MYCOMP\c$\Program Files
```

That should resolve your issues. Note that will need to remove your *SUBST* mapping prior to doing this.

Comment: Mapped drives do not have recycle bin functionality, unfortunately.  Note that I too have never seen this behaviour before.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be mapping drives to network shares.  SUBST is used to map a drive to a local folder.

Comment: It *is* a local folder on that computer--`D:` maps to `C:\something`.  It just happens to be a network share as well.  I only included that piece of information because it was one of the ways that I could actually access it while this glitch was happening...

Comment: My bad.  One thing I have noticed in the past, is that a SUBST drive shows as 'Disconnected' after a reboot until you go browse it in explorer.  That may be why it is not available on the run command.  Maybe try writing a DOS batch file that sits on C that will start your command and change the drive to D...

Comment: I have the SUBST in my logon.cmd script, so it always connects properly from the start.

After a reboot, it's working correctly from the run command again.  I haven't been experiencing this problem since the reboot.  Thanks, though.